# file names starting with a string in the format of *.txt give error in FOR

Tags: windows, script

I have a piece in my windows batch script. It runs fine as :

```
for /f %%C in ('Find /V /C "" ^< %SFTP_INDIR%\Location.20150528060210.txt') do set count=%%C
```

But when run instead of a hardcoded name of .txt it fails :

```
for /f %%C in ('Find /V /C "" ^< %SFTP_INDIR%\Location*.txt') do set count=%%C
```

I do not want to hard code name of the .txt file. Can anyone suggest how can i pick file name starting with "Location" here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### When run with a wildcard specification of `...*.txt` it fails

```
 for /f %%C in ('Find /V /C "" ^< %SFTP_INDIR%\Location*.txt') do set count=%%C
```

The above command will not work because you cannot **redirect** multiple files (a wildcard specification) to be the input to `find`.

The following command will work:

```
for /f %%C in ('Find /V /C "" %SFTP_INDIR%\Location*.txt') do set count=%%C
```

However, I don't think it will give you the output you are hoping for.

This is because your `for /f` command only matches the **first** token on the line, which is `----------`.

---

#### How do I get the number of rows in a variable?

Use the following batch file (test.cmd):

```
@echo off
setlocal
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%c in ('Find /V /C "" *.txt') do (
  set _count=%%c
  set count=!_count:~1!
  echo !count!
  )
```

- `!count!` contains the number of lines in each matching file.
- replace `*.txt` with your own wildcard filename `%SFTP_INDIR%\Location*.txt`
- `count=!_count:~1!` strips the leading space from `_count` (there is a leading space because we are using `:` as a delimeter to get the last part of each line.

Example output:

```
F:\test>test
5
2
7
5
39
39
75
1
5
0
11
5

F:\test>
```

Comment: David, 

for /f %%C in ('Find /V /C "" %SFTP_INDIR%\Location*.txt') do set count=%%C 
did not work . variable "count"  did not fetch any value. Is there an alternate way of counting the number of rows in a file by giving a wildcard specification assuming there is only one file starting with Location? my files will usually have the format Location.<time_stamp>.txt hence i need write a general code to run on Location file with any timestamp.

Comment: yes. i need to get only the number of rows in a variable.